# Pass useState type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple app like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import AddToList from './components/AddToList'
import List from './components/List'

export interface IProps{
  name: string
  age: number
  url: string
  note: string
}

const App = () => {

  const[people, setPeople] = useState([{
    name: 'chris',
    url: '',
    age: 21,
    note: 'note note'
  }])

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>People Invited</h2>
      <List people={people}/>
      <AddToList people setPeople/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Just a simple useState with one object and an interface.

I have a `List` component to show the objects in people.

I want to have a form in `AddToList` to add to people.

I'm passing `people` and `setPeople` to `AddToList`

```
import React from 'react'
import {IProps as Props} from '../App'

interface IProps{
    people: Props[]
    setPeople:any
}

const AddToList:React.FC<IProps> = ({people, setPeople}) => {
  return (
    <div>AddToList</div>
  )
}

export default AddToList
```

In the app `<AddToList people setPeople/>` people here is erroring beacuse of the type of people here in `AddToList`

```
interface IProps{
    people: Props[]
    setPeople:any
}
```

what should the type be here `people: Props[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<MyComponent foo />
```

Is actually just shorthand for:

```
<MyComponent foo={true} />
```

It does *not* mean:

```
<MyComponent foo={foo} />
```

If you want to pass in those props you either need:

```
<AddToList people={people} setPeople={setPeople} />
```

Or you can spread them as an object:

```
<AddToList {...{ people, setPeople }} />
```

---

Also the correct type for a react state setter function is:

```
Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>
```

Where `T` is the type of your state. In that case that would be:

```
interface IProps{
    people: Props[]
    setPeople: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Props[]>>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying exactly what is going on (which is what Typescript is telling us). Also +1 for adding the type to their dispatch even though they didn't ask about it.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the line from
`<AddToList people setPeople/>`
To
`<AddToList people={people} setPeople={setPeople}/>` and it worked for me.
The error typescript was throwing for me was that type "boolean" was not assignable to type Props[]. So when I did a assign like this it worked, however it may vary depending on your typescript version.